# How do I get vpc_id so I can create a VPC subnet in Terraform?

Tags: terraform, terraform-provider-aws, amazon-vpc, subnet

I am creating an AWS VPC with a single public subnet in a brand-new Terraform project, consisting only of a `main.tf` file. In that file I am using two resource blocks, `aws_vpc` and `aws_subnet`. The second resource must be attached to the first using the `vpc_id` attribute. The value of this attribute is created only upon apply, so it cannot be hard-coded. How do I get the ID of the resource I just created, so I can use it in the subsequent block?

```
resource "aws_vpc" "my_vpc" {
  cidr_block = "102.0.0.0/16"
  tags = {
    Name = "My-VPC"
  }
}

resource "aws_subnet" "my_subnet" {
  vpc_id = # what goes here?
  cidr_block = "102.0.0.0/24"
  tags = {
    Name = "My-Subnet"
  }
}
```

[The docs](https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/aws/latest/docs/data-sources/subnet#example-usage) give the example of `data.aws_subnet.selected.vpc_id` for `vpc_id`. The value of this appears to depend on two other blocks, `variable` and `data`. I am having a hard time seeing how to wire these up to my VPC. I tried copying them directly from the docs. Upon running `terraform plan` I get the prompt:

```
var.subnet_id
  Enter a value:
```

This is no good; I want to pull the value from the VPC I just created, not enter it at the command prompt. Where do I specify that the data source is the resource that I just created in the previous code block?

I have heard that people create a separate file to hold Terraform variables. Is that what I should to do here? It seems like it should be so basic to get an ID from one resource and use it in the next. Is there a one-liner to pass along this information?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can just call the VPC in the subnet block by referencing Terraform's pointer. Also, doing this tells Terraform that the VPC needs to be created first and destroyed second.

```
resource "aws_vpc" "my_vpc" {
  cidr_block = "102.0.0.0/16"
  tags = {
    Name = "My-VPC"
  }
}

resource "aws_subnet" "my_subnet" {
  vpc_id = aws_vpc.my_vpc.id
  cidr_block = "102.0.0.0/24"
  tags = {
    Name = "My-Subnet"
  }
}
```

Comment: This appears to be exactly what I was looking for -- in fact, almost suspiciously simple based on my prior experience with Terraform. Is there some disadvantage to not using `locals` or `variables`?

Comment: @JohnSkilesSkinner if you want Terraform to create the VPC and manage it, this is the solution. If you want to create the VPC outside of Terraform, and just reference it, then you would use `locals` or `variables` or `data` lookups.

Comment: Although if you don't want terraform to manage the VPC you could also just hardcode the id once you made it. The advantage to doing it the way in my answer is that Terraform can build a tree of dependencies. It is pretty good at figuring out what order to build and destroy objects based on that tree.

Answer (score 1):

> I want to pull the value from the VPC I just created,

You can't do this. You can't dynamically populate variables from data sources. But you could use `local` instead:

```
 locals {
   subnet_id = data.aws_subnet.selected.id
 }
```

and refer to it as `local.subnet_id`.